# moving php project from fedora to windows wamp error

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a php project and I am trying to move it from fedora to windows. I moved the files and I can get to them and I can get to the database as well but I get a strange error

```
SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for

( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\wamp\www\portfolio\templates\sell_form.php on line 21
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0029  259504  {main}( )   ..\sell.php:0
2   0.1515  304656  render( )   ..\sell.php:67
```

this the file

```
<table class="table table-hover center-table table-bordered">
        <tr>
        <th>Symbol</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Shares</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
<?php foreach ($shares as $row): ?>

        <tr>
        <td><?= $row["symbol"]?></td>
        <td><?= $row["name"]?></td>
        <td><?= $row["shares"]?></td>
        <td>$<?= number_format($row["price"],4)?></td>
        <td>$<?= number_format($row["total"],4)?></td>
        </tr>

<? endforeach ?>

<tr>
    <td>CASH</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>$<?= number_format($cash[0]["cash"], 4)?></td>

</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: go to the line where the error points out.. and highlight it in the post so we know were to starts checking..

Comment: It points to the end of the file the </table> tag. This file is called from a controller file which adds the header and footer also. The project works on fedora I just want to move to windows.

Comment: its because you didnt end your loop in right.. doest have semicolon ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

forgot the comma there and also the php tag, unless you have short tags turned on, it wont work.

Comment: Thanks the ; and php was the problem but somehow I wasn't having this problem on fedora.

Comment: i think its because in every <?php ?> fedora tends to end it in a manner to avoid unended scripts..

Answer (score 1):

your ending statement for loop is not properly set

```
<? endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks the ; and php was the problem but somehow I wasn't having this problem on fedora.